# tf.map_fn & tf.range confusing result

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is the reproducible code:

```
def _test_fn(tp):
    tp0 = tp[0]
    tp1 = tp[1]
    result = tf.range(tp0, tp1)
    return result

ll = tf.constant([[1,4], [5, 7]])

result = tf.map_fn(lambda tp: _test_fn(tp), ll)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(result)
```

This code is expected to output a `[[1,2,3], [5,6]]`. However, I get an error of:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): TensorArray has inconsistent shapes.  Index 0 has shape: [3] but index 1 has shape: [2]

Do I misunderstand the usage of `tf.range()` and `tf.map_fn()` or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first application of `_test_fn` will return range(1,4), which is [1,2,3]. The second application will return range(5,7), which is [5,6]. Tensorflow will then attempt to put all of these into one tensor, i.e. [[1,2,3],[5,6]]. This is not a valid tensor since the two rows have different lengths, so this code crashes. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Thanks. You are right. Tensorflow will not allow tensor of variable-size tensor, which I consider a major defeat. I am trying to create such a tensor, because I have variable length input.

Comment: Depending on your application, you could consider either padding the different rows to the same length, or using `SparseTensor` instead.